# Dynamic route not detecting change in API response on page change

Tags: svelte, sapper

I'm quite new to Svelte/Sapper so please bear with me. I've got a dynamic route which fetches from an API url, and depending on the "bundle" it should render a different component. The route works fine on load, or refresh, but when clicking between the pages it doesn't detect the "bundle" and tries to load the wrong component:

[...slug].svelte

```
<script context="module">
    export async function preload({ params }) {
        const res = await this.fetch(process.env.SVELTE_APP_API_URL + '/alias?_format=json&slug='+ params.slug);
        if (res.status === 200) {
            const data = await res.json();
            return { node: data };
        } else {
            this.error(res.status, data.message);
        }
    }
</script>


<script>
    import Article from '../bundles/Article.svelte';
    import Page from '../bundles/Page.svelte';
    import CustomPage from '../bundles/CustomPage.svelte';
    import Error from './_error.svelte';

    export let node;

    const bundles = {
        article: Article,
        page: Page,
        custom_page: CustomPage
    };
    let Component;
    let status = '';
    let error = {
        message: ''
    };


    if(bundles[node.bundle]){
        Component = bundles[node.bundle];
    }else{
        Component = Error;
        status = '404';
        error.message = 'Page not found';
    }

</script>


{node.bundle} // This is correct!

{#key [node.bundle]}
<svelte:component node={node} status={status} error={error} this={Component}/>
{/key}. // This is incorrect!
```

It does fetch the correct data however - if I click between two different "Page" bundles it renders the correct content.

If I'm going about things the completely wrong way please let me know :)

Answer (score 0):

I found that I had to make the component variable reactive:

```
$: component = bundles[node.bundle];
```